# Correlation between three random variables

Tags: random-variables, correlation

Suppose I have three random variables $X,Y,Z$. I know that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated and that $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ and $\mathbb{E}[YZ]=\mathbb{E}[Y]E[Z]$. By any chance, does this mean that also $X$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated?

Comment: Consider $X,Y$ independent and $Z=X$.

Comment: Take $X$ and $Y$ independent. And $Z=\frac{X}{2}$. Then what happens?

Comment: oops....@nejimban and I posted simultaneously...lol

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! I understand that in general $X$ and $Z$ may be correlated. I think this answers my question.